# Is there any way we can formulate QUBO for finding MST on Dwave Quantum Annealer?

Tags: optimization, solver, minimum-spanning-tree, quantum-computing, dwave

I have an undirected weighted connected graph and I am stuck in formulating QUBO to find MST which span all vertices and provide acyclic subgraph as the output however I cannot seem to find the solution and I am very new to the Quantum Computing. For Quantum Computing, I am using D-WAVE Leap. Although, I am getting the output when I use NetworkX library **"minimum_spanning_tree()"** function but I want the same output to be obtained when I use the same graph for the problem to be solved on D-WAVE annealers, be it be Quantum, Hyrbid and Simulated Annealing? Is there a way the QUBO be formulated for that?

I reviewed this research paper(https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9367437) and created the objective function and constraints and when I run it on dwave solver "Advantage_System4.1" I get multiple samples which by post processing steps, I somehow obtained the MST but if there are more than 2 cycles in the graph, I cannot get it. Also, when it gets to Simulated Annealing and Hybrid Solver, I don't get the adequate responses.